# Preferred order of writing latitude & longitude tuples in GIS services

Tags: google-maps, gis, latitude-longitude

When dealing with GIS source code you often need to write latitude and longitude coordinate tuples.

E.g. in Google Maps links (123, 456):

http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=214518704716144912556.00046d7689a99e95b721c&msa=0&ll=123,456&spn=0.007996,0.026865

Which is preferred order (and why?)

- latitude, longitude
- longitude, latitude

I have seen both being used in various systems and I hope to find some evidence to stick with other one.

Is there a standard practice, and if so, what is it / what are they?

Comment: instead of preferred order, you can check a compilation of cases: http://www.macwright.org/lonlat/

Comment: It's `latitude, longitude` order

Comment: see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293897/is-srid-4326-lon-lat-or-lat-lon

Comment: Good reason for living **west of 90°W** (roughly the Mississippi River in the US), or **east of 90°E** (roughly Bhutan). Like finding out if a clock shows military time by waiting until the afternoon.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming but about geography. It is also an opinion-based question.

Comment: Thank you for your vote @TylerH - if you read the answers there are several technical specifications that answer the question. So while everyone is entitled to their opinion, there are standards the software industry should follow and then those standards have justifications why they picked one or another. The fact that making this thing opinionated or not about programming has caused a lot of bugs in the past and that's why it is better to stick to the standards.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa The difference is that your question does not ask what the required order is for a particular technical specification (which would likely be just as off-topic as a request for off-site documentation information), but rather what the 'preferred' method is [*in general*]. What is preferred changes based on the person you ask and the purpose/context of the usage. As the answers here have shown, both orderings have a substantial following. Subsequently, the issue of programming relation is still entirely unaddressed.

Comment: I edited the question title. Happy now @TylerH?

Comment: @TylerH Geographic Information Systems (GIS) and Geographic Information Application (GIA) are a subset of computer science. It was there in the question since the beginning in the question body. It was there in tags. Here is a Wikipedia article for  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system - I suggest you pay more careful attention to the problem domain in this question

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I have no issue with GIS questions on Stack Overflow. This isn't a GIS question; it's a "how should I order latitude/longitude" question... there's not even a specific GIS application you're asking for. This question is still opinion-based (any question asking for "preferred methods" is opinion-based), too broad (what context, scenario, or application are you asking about? As the answers show, it's different based on those criteria), and not about programming (latitude and longitude are not programming terms but geography terms).

Comment: @TylerH How would you recommend methe question so that it satiesfies your criteria?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa For future such questions, if there's a specific GIS application you're asking about, you should specify that in the question, and ask how it *needs* to be ordered, rather than what ordering is *preferred*. That way answers can be objective rather than subjective. But in this question's case, it's too late to edit it, as Stack Exchange policy is to not edit questions in such a way that they invalidate existing/established answers, and there are multiple answers already suggesting both orders.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

EPSG:4326 specifically states that the coordinate order should be latitude, longitude. Many software packages still use longitude, latitude ordering. This situation has wreaked unimaginable havoc on project deadlines and programmer sanity.

The best guidance one can offer is to be fully aware of the expected axis order of each component in your software stack. PostGIS expects lng/lat. WFS 1.0 uses lng/lat, but WFS 1.3.0 defers to the standard and uses lat/lng. GeoTools defaults to lat/lng but can be overridden with a system property.

The GeoTools docs on the history and explanation of the problem are worth a read:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html

Comment: Finally a authoritative response :)

Comment: I rarely see as answer on SO.com which states **why** this well. Beats crap out of those "because MongoDB uses it" answers.

Comment: Your link disagrees with you; _In the EPSG database, 4326 maps to a geographic CRS with (latitude, longitude) axis order. However, most software in the field understand EPSG:4326 as a geographic CRS with (longitude, latitude) axis order, because legacy OGC specifications were designed that way._

Comment: First two sentences from my answer: *EPSG:4326 specifically states that the coordinate order should be latitude, longitude. Many software packages still use longitude, latitude ordering.* Isn't that exactly the same?

Comment: If anyone else has issues with Google Maps and supplying a KML file to it, the order is Longitude/Latitude!! No documentation for the KML file says this!!

Comment: For the sake of conforming to a standard, imho Google and Apple are in the wrong here and should switch to (lng, lat). Here's a list of who uses what https://macwright.org/lonlat/

Comment: "No documentation for the KML file says this" is incorrect. https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#point "A single tuple consisting of floating point values for longitude, latitude, and altitude (in that order)."

Comment: Just got caught out by this using MongoDB - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/polygon/#op._S_polygon

Comment: I was looking for the order of Google Map coordinates, it is now latitude, longitude. @Turnerj, all these discussion make me confusing, so I doubled checked my address with https://www.gps-coordinates.net/

Answer (score 35):

The prefered order is by convention `latitude, longitude`. This was presumably standardized by
the [International Maritime Organization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Maritime_Organization) 
as reported [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_goes_first_Longitude_or_Latitude). Google also uses this order in its [Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) and [Earth](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/). I remember this order by thinking of alphabetic order of `latitude, longitude`.

Comment: Except in KML files. There coordinates are stored as lng,lat,alt; probably because that can be translated to x,y,z

Answer (score 30):

The correct order is longitude, latitude, in virtually all professional GIS applications, as it is in conventional math (ie, `f(x ,y, z)`).  The GeoJSON standard is fairly typical and succinct:

```
The order of elements must follow x, y, z order
(easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a 
projected coordinate reference system, or longitude,
latitude, altitude for coordinates in a geographic
coordinate reference system).
```

The same is true of the primary Open Geospatial Consortium standards (WKT and WKB, and extensions like EWKB). Likewise Google may output the order in Lat/Lon to make it more familiar to users who grew up with that custom (ie from navigation standards like IMO, rather than computational ones.) But the KML standard itself is like virtually all other GIS systems:

```
The KML encoding of every kml:Location and coordinate
tuple uses geodetic longitude, geodetic latitude, and
altitude (in that order).
```

Good rule of thumb: if you know what a tuple is and are programming, you should be using `lon`,`lat`. I would even say this applies if your end user (say a pilot or a ship captain) will prefer to view the output in `lat`,`lon`. You can switch the order in your UI if necessary, but the overwhelming majority of your data (shapefiles, geojson, etc.) will be in the normal Cartesian order.

Comment: I see some disagreement here :I TWo choices to pick - too many!

Comment: Readers should note that ISO 6709 explicitly states you should always use [lat, lon] format in any UI and it's not - as might be inferred - merely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: The ISO standard specifically only applies to form inputs, not storage mechanisms, software or formats. [This](https://macwright.com/lonlat/) is a handy summary.

Comment: The Simple Features, GeoSPARQL and GML specifications are clear in this regard: geometries are encoded with the axes order declared by the CRS. Although some exceptions exist, most software complies with these specifications.

Answer (score 10):

ISO 6709 standardizes listing the order as latitude, longitude for safety reasons. Graham's explanation above sounds correct to me as well. Someone suggested this answer isn't related to the question--it absolutely is, and explains why the order is often given as latitude, longitude.

This is how it has been listed for however long navigators have been using the system; changing that now would be confusing, and as ISO suggests, potentially dangerous. GIS softwares, like ArcMap, list them the other way around because that is the typical convention for x,y coordinate pairs. Latitude is y, longitude is x, so that's how Arc lists them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709 says that if the order isn't specified, it should be assumed to be latitude, lon. The doc itself says it's Especially important in the UI. "The sequence of coordinates is critical. Historical conventional usage gives the latitude value before the longitude value. Users in the marine and air navigation fields, and involved with emergency response are used
to seeing latitude and longitude given in this order. If the height or depth is also given, it follows longitude.
Presenting coordinate values in another order has life-safety implications."

Comment: The great thing about standards is that there are so many of them... The OP asked of the "preferred order". ISO 6709 strings are not even tuples the OP seemed to wonder about (I've had to parse and produce ISO 6709 strings in the past and tuples are easier).

Answer (score 9):

By convention in 'real-life', when giving a position, the latitude (i.e. North/South) is always given 1st, e.g. 20°N 56°W (although, this doesn't follow normal convention if thinking about a standard Cartesian grid); similarly, all co-ordinates on Wikipedia follow this convention (e.g. see location for Southampton: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southampton).  To save confusion, especially when units aren't being included, I'd always recommend that the latitude is given 1st in a tuple.

Answer (score 9):

So the preferred order depends on personal preference!

Latitude came first; the equinox has been known for millenia, as the days the "sun crosses the equator"; in March crossing from S to N and Sept from N to S.The only question might have been whether the Equator should have been 0 or 90 degrees. By taking 0 deg, the angle between vertical and the midday solar zenith on the equinox is the latitude of a location, everywhere on the planet. The prime latitude, or prime parallel effectively defined itself.

Longitude could only be by agreement. Britain put up a Longitude prize. Britain needed its ships to know where they were and needed better maps. Harrison (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-g27KS0yiY) produced an accurate marine chronometer; they sent mapmaking voyaging journeys eg James Cook 1770's. Britain therefore claimed the Prime Meridian by using Greenwich as 000deg for their maps. After 100 years of their use, the Prime Meridian was accepted internationally, in 1884.

In Christopher Columbus time Latitude was the only number they had. The strategy was to traverse a parallel before turning left or right for destination; watching for clouds or birds. Measuring speed in knots every hour was common but did not account for currents. Perhaps Columbus's greatest achievement was getting back home from the West Indies four times. Without that, land he discovered could not be added to the maps.

Read "Longitude" by Dava Sobel (ISBN: 9780007214228)

Comment: I think he means programmatically and with a technical reference (but I could be mistaken). The history lesson was interesting, though.

Comment: This not related to the question, but definitely interesting. Thanks :)

Comment: But it does make sense, for if only map coordinates would be used, it would be without question that the order would be longitude, latitude, as in X, Y; the confusion only exists because of the hundreds of years of precedence of saying (and hearing) latitude, longitude everywhere.

Comment: Axes order is not a matter of personal preference, it is a feature of the CRS. The specifications from the OGC/ISO are clear, it just happens that not all software packages follow them. You are also mistaken regarding Colon, not only wasn't the return from the Caribbean a major feat compared with other sea journeys of the time, the accuracy of longitude measurements in the XV century is well in display in the Cantino map.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I've never seen anything but latitude followed by longitude.

And, when using + and - instead of N and S, it's always been + is N and - is S.

I have observed variation when using + and - for E and W. Generally + has been E and - has been W. However, on older applications where they were dealing overhwlemingly with W longitudes, I've seen + be W and - be E.

Hopefully you'll not have to be dealing with applications that old.

Comment: It's easily observable when you work with worldwide applications.

Comment: Just type any pair of longitude and latitude coordinates into Google maps and you'll see it interprets it as (long, lat), not vice versa. That's an example of a very widely-used system.

Comment: @cazort For whatever reason, that doesn't happen here. For example, my hometown of Eugene, Oregon is at approximately N 44.1, W 123.1. If in maps.google.com I enter 44.1 -123.1, it goes to Eugene. If I enter -123.1 44, it tells me it can't find it. Interestingly, though, if I enter 123.1 W 44 N, it figures it out and goes to Eugene, so there is some flexibility. Also https://www.reference.com/technology/enter-gps-coordinates-google-maps-3de6c79239e4ce0d# appears to indicate tht lat/long is the preferred order. Also, for what it's worth, Google Earth uses lat/long.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from GeoJSON spec, which others have already mentioned, there are other practical cases where longitude,latitide order is recommended, even mandatory - e.g.: [geospatial indexing in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-NewSphericalModel). If you get the order wrong there, your queries will return wrong results, as if performed again a transposed dataset.

Comment: Lots of other examples: WMS, WKT, OpenLayers, Mapbox, Shapefile, Redis, even Google KML (despite using lat/lon in their maps API).

Answer (score 1):

Longitude then Latitude (lon, lat).

When projected to Mercator longitude defines the x direction and latitude defines the y direction.  Most geometry libraries strictly uses this format of (lon, lat) as it is the most intuitive way to think of geographic coordinates in a 2D plane.

Comment: So, if that's most intuitive way of thinking, why is Google Earth blog called [Lat-Long Blog](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/) while they use lon-lat in KML?

Comment: Basically, it's that navigators have traditionally used the lat-lon ordering, so if you messed with that ordering you might screw up your navigations. So google is using the traditional for a blog and the 2D plane ordering for their data structure. @mkennedy answers this best in her answer to the same question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/latlon-or-lonlat-whats-the-right-way-to-display-coordinates-and-inputs/6048#6048